# Question B6 on Putnam 2016

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

I didn't make any headway on this during the Putnam, mainly because I wasn't going to waste my time on a B6 question which should be the most difficult one on the exam.  It seems really intriguing, and was wondering if anyone had any good ideas on how to tackle it or a solution:$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k2^n+1}=$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm assuming what it converges to, but it literally was just that and no words

Comment: Not sure if it would help, but the right-most sum can be turned into a geometric series, and then we would have a triple sum.

Comment: I put good odds on getting somewhere by replacing $2^n$ with $x^n$ and doing some calculus.

Comment: Perhaps expanding the double sum into a matrix would help.

Comment: I answered by factoring a $k 2^n$ out of the denominator of the second summand to make it into a convergent geometric series, then after playing around with sums and combining things to simplify, it ends up as a telescoping sum that evaluates to 1.

Comment: I would let $a(k)$ represent the inner series, and show that the above series is the same as $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{a(k) - a(2k)}{k}$. The expression $a(k) - a(2k)$ gives a telescoping series with sum $1/(k+1)$, so the result is $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = 1$.

Comment: A typical brainteaser  puzzle for young people and not fit for old conceited men.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Let $S_{0}$ and $S_{1}$ be the sums $\sum_{k}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\times2^n+1}$ with $k$ running over all *odd* and *even* positive integers respectively so that we have, $$S = S_1-S_0 = (S_1+S_0)-2S_0...(1)$$ Thus, we can write $k =2\alpha$ for $S_1$ to get $$S_1 = \sum_{\alpha=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\alpha} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\alpha2^{n+1}+1}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}(S_0+S_1) + \sum_{\alpha=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\alpha(\alpha+1)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}(S_0+S_1) + \frac{1}{2}$$ as the last sum telescopes which can checked very easily giving us $1/2$. This gives us $S=1$ using $(1)$. Hope it helps.